# How to loop through a string using find() C++

Tags: c++

The loop in the program seems to execute at least once, even if there are no occurences of the substring. Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int countSubstrings(const string& original_string, const string& substr) {
    int number_of_ocurrences = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = original_string.find(original_string, 0); i != string::npos;
     i = original_string.find(substr, i)) {
        number_of_ocurrences++;
        i++;
    }
    return number_of_ocurrences;
}

int main() {
    string input;
    while (1) {
        cout << "Enter a a line of text: ";
        getline(cin, input, '\n');
        cout << '\n';
        cout << "Number of ocurrences of the word needle: ";
        cout << countSubstrings(input, "needle") << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Initially when you set `i` in your for loop you have

```
original_string.find(original_string, 0)
```

So you are searching the string for itself which it will find.  I believe you meant to have

```
original_string.find(substr, 0)
```